# React-Navigation: "react/jsx-runtime".jsx is not a function (it is undefined)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

After installing react-navigation and copying their example, I get the following error
`_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[5], "react/jsx-runtime").jsx is not a function (it is undefined)`

No idea where this comes from.
I tried "yarn add react/jsx-runtime", no help.
I also tried deleting node_modules/ and re-type "yarn install"

App.tsx

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';                               
                                                                                              
import Navigation from './src/MyNavigation/MyNavigation'                                                                                                                                    
import Store from './src/Store/configureStore'                                                
                                                                                              
function App(): JSX.Element {                                                                                                                          
  return (                                                                                                                                             
      <NavigationContainer>                                                                   
        <Navigation/>                                                                         
      </NavigationContainer>                                                                                                                                         
  );                                                                                          
}                                                                                             
                                                                                              
                                                                                              
export default App;
```

and the src/MyNavigation/MyNavigation

````
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';                     
                                                                                              
import TimePracticeScreen from '../screens/TimePractice';                                     
import Charts from '../screens/Charts';                                                       
                                                                                              
                                                                                              
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();                                                       
                                                                                              
function TabNavigator() {                                                                     
  return (                                                                                    
      <Tab.Navigator>                                                                         
        <Tab.Screen name="Train" component={TimePracticeScreen} />                            
        <Tab.Screen name="Graph" component={Charts} />                                        
      </Tab.Navigator>                                                                        
  );                                                                                          
}                                                                                             
                              
export default TabNavigator```
````

Comment: I'm having the same issue :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't what caused the issue but I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-native-navigation-tutorial/) step by step, and I got a bottom tab navigation working :-/

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I forgot the additional steps where we need to add react-native-screens to the project. After adding it, the error disappeared.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started#installing-dependencies-into-a-bare-react-native-project

`yarn add react-native-screens`